# Can I Update and Setting Multiple Variables with Java in IntelliJ? No, I can't

Tags: java, variables, intellij-idea

Cosmics! I'm very proud of myself because now I can share my first code with deeply understanding of the subject. The thing is that I'm not sure If I can do what I understand. Probably my mistakes are a way more foolish that I can imagine, but I'm about to ask you: can I resolve this problems?

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        System.out.println("Hello Java!");

    }int medicals;
    medicals = 0;
    medicals = medicals + 100;
    medicals = 20;
    medicals = medicals + 5;
    System.out.println("medicals");
    System.out.println(medicals);
    int medicals;
    int pharmacies;
    medicals = 200;
    pharmacies = 1;
    medicals = medicals - 5;
    medicals = medicals - 10;
    medicals = medicals - 15;
    medicals = medicals - 20;
    medicals = 5;
    System.out.println(medicals);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kg3I.jpg)

Comment: One way just edit that `}` at line 9 and place it at the end. Another is to make sure people are able to see that error right up here and not landing to some other page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't declare the same variable twice (`int medicals;` has been declared twice in your code). I have removed it and added your code inside the main method,

```
package com.company;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        System.out.println("Hello Java!");

        int medicals;
        medicals = 0;
        medicals = medicals + 100;
        medicals = 20;
        medicals = medicals + 5;
        System.out.println("medicals");
        System.out.println(medicals);
        int pharmacies;
        medicals = 200;
        pharmacies = 1;
        medicals = medicals - 5;
        medicals = medicals - 10;
        medicals = medicals - 15;
        medicals = medicals - 20;
        medicals = 5;
        System.out.println(medicals);
    }
}
```